# Как сделать редирект и передать данные POSTом?

Tags: php, api, платежи

Есть API платежной системы, который принимает данные только по POST и выдает страницу для ввода платежной информации. Перед отправкой формы мне нужно редактировать данные в зависимости от введенной пользователем информации.

Пример:

> Пользователь выбирает тип услуги,   информация отправляется
>    в нужный обработчик(адрес), после чего результат постом передается на
>   страницу API.

Можно конечно сделать промежуточную страницу со скрытыми полями, но по условию ее быть не должно.

Comment: Что за платежная система такая, у которой нет примеров кода? Не годится или вы просто не посмотрели демо, а стоит заглянуть, ведь там все написано и показано.

Comment: @And , а причем тут пример кода и демо, об этом речь не шла. Я могу с формы отправить post с сумой и другими данными с формы на страницу сервиса, и будет все работать. Но перед отправкой мне нужно обработать данные.  Вы внимательно ознакомились с вопросом, а стоит, там все написано.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно неправильно понимаю саму проблему, но я бы сделал так:

Завести переменную - $type_of_service

В форме делаем select, что-то вроде (если честно, не помню как там аргумент name  у select`а точно должен выглядеть, но это гуглимо)

```
<form action="select1.php" method="post">
   <p><select name="$type_of_service">
    <option disabled>Выберите героя</option>
    <option value="Чебурашка">Чебурашка</option>
    <option selected value="Крокодил Гена">Крокодил Гена</option>
    <option value="Шапокляк">Шапокляк</option>
    <option value="Крыса Лариса">Крыса Лариса</option>
   </select></p>
   <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
</form>
```

После чего в select1.php выполнить обработку в зависимости от:

```
$_REQUEST['type_of_service']
```

После чего отправить POST запрос, собрав его вручную, проще всего с помощью cURL

```
$params = array(
    'параметр' => значение,
    ...
);

# Создание curl
$curl = curl_init();

# Установка параметров
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'адрес');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

# Оправка post запроса
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Вы не совсем поняли, как в данном, та и в любом случае работает API платежной системы, я специально уточнил: "принимает данные только по POST и выдает страницу для ввода платежной информации". Пользователь должен попасть на страницу сервиса для ввода  реквизитов своей карты, в то же время эта страница должна получить POST данные: сумму, валюту, назначения платежа . Передавая данные curl - пользователь не попадает на страницу сервиса.